# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined (Phaser)

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

im sort of new at this website, currently working on this mini RPG phaser game in brackets. Assuming no spelling errors that i can see, every time i go live, i get stuck with this dang error in my main.js, i looked over my main.js and my index.html, cant find the issue, my phaser.js is under js/phaser.js.

```js
var RPG = RPG || {};

var game = new Phaser.Game(640, 480, Phaser.CANVAS);

game.state.add("TitleState", new RPG.TitleState());
game.state.start("TitleState");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <title>KawaiiRPG</title>
    </head>
    
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            background-color: black;
        }
    </style>

    
    <body>
    
       <script src="js/phaser.js"></script>
        
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        
    </body>


</html>
```

[image: screen shot of error]

Comment: Right, so, `new Phaser.Game()` is giving you something that doesn't have a `state` property. What does the documentation say `new Phaser()` should return?

Comment: The web docs don't cover anything higher than phaser 2.6

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that, afaik, Phaser 3 (shown in your screenshot's console) has to little documentation right know; most documentation and examples you can find refers to Phaser 2, or early betas of Phaser 3.

I'm new to Phaser (and game development in general) and I'm having problems too reading Phaser 2 examples and figuring out how to make them work in Phaser 3. So here is my try...

**What is wrong:** in Phaser 3 there are no *states* but *scenes*, each of which acts as an *world* by it self; and they are managed differently to the *states* in previous versions of Phaser (https://phaser.io/phaser3/contributing/part5).

**Solution:** Not sure how to dynamically add a *scene* to a game, but by using a configuration object you can set the initial scene when creating the *Game* object:

```
var myRpgTitleScene = {
  preload: function(){},
  create: function(){},
  update: function(){}
}
var config = {
    type: Phaser.CANVAS,  
    width: 640,
    height: 480
  },
  scene: myRpgTitleScene
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```